# Telegram BOT -- Implementing the search in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, telegram-bot

I'm creating a telegram bot that searchs for words in a online dictionary, the problem comes when I need to create the command in Telegram for searching in that dictionary, at the momment I have this:

```
from rae import Drae
drae = Drae()

  if text.startswith('/'):
     if text =='/define':
        drae.search(u' ')  # The problem is here, I don't know how to implement the command and the word who the client wants to search.
        setEnabled(chat_id, True)
```

- I'm using this Telegram API in Python: https://github.com/yukuku/telebot
- And this API for the Dictionary: https://github.com/dialelo/rae-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.

```
from rae import Drae

drae = Drae()

if text.startswith('/'):
  if text.startswith('/define'):
    try:
      [command, data] = text.split(' ',1)
    except:
      send('Write: /define <word>')
    meanings = drae.search(data) 
    reply(str(meanings)) 
    setEnabled(chat_id, True)
```